# Синоним и русификация для function-overloading

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю создать синоним для [function-overloading](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-overloading) вида [перегрузка-функций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9) и сделать русскоязычный вариант основным. А может быть и вовсе отказаться от англоязычной метки.

Comment: В каких отношениях находятся [tag:перегрузка-функций], [tag:перегрузка-операторов] (72 вопроса, синоним с [tag:перегрузка]) и [tag:перегрузка-свойств] (1 вопрос)?

Comment: @NickVolynkin оператор - частный случай функции, когда вместо имени используется знак типа + - & и т.д. Хотя есть и операторы, заданные словами (sizeof, new). Это в контексте c++ если. Свойства - по сути синтаксический сахар для удобного определения пары функций get/set. Может в каких-то языках есть особенности на этот счет, затрудняюсь сказать.

Comment: Определения-то я знаю. :) Вопрос, нужно ли метки объединять или как-то упоминать одну в описании другой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin может быть тогда вообще есть смысл оставить отдельные метки "перегрузка", "функции", "свойства", "операторы", а составные убрать?

Comment: @alexolut не надо разделять, а то будет у нас толпа вопросов про перегрузку сайтов, ПК, программ и линий связи.

Comment: @Kromster про разумность разделение можно отдельный вопрос будет задать.